# ASP custom validation with validation summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm working on a legacy application that has an ASP web page that is used to send emails to various recipients. The page has various input fields (`TextBox`es and `CheckBoxList`s) with `RequiredFieldValidator`s. The validations messages are displayed on a `ValidationSummary` control

The page also has some `asp:Button`s that each trigger the validation. What I want to do is unhook all but one of these buttons from the validation that is performed on the page. I've tried to change the buttons to normal html buttons with an `onserverclick` event, but the validations is still trigured.

One of these buttons:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetRecipient" runat="server" OnClick="btnGetRecipient_Click" Text="Create Recipient List" Style="height: 26px" />
```

As should be apparent, this is a button that retrieves a set of recipients. It gets these recipients from a database and then populates a `GridView`. Now, I don't want to get a validation message stating that the Subject and Body of the email is required when I'm retrieving the recipients.

Comment: Take a look at the [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property for your controls

Comment: @RedTaz: Aaah, that's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `false` for those controls which cause a page postback but should not trigger ASP.NET validation.

The default for this property is `true`, so by default every control which causes a postback will raise validation events.